# How to create a Lambda function for AWS IoT Button

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-iot

I've read though a couple of tutorials, and watched several videos about this topic, but I'm not able to reproduce the steps shown there.

My AWS IoT Button is configurd correctly and works as it should. I then go to the Lambda Management console, and create a new Lambda function from one of the templates. The screen that appears now is different from all the tutorials and videos. Anyway, I have to choose a trigger and select the IoT Button there. The GUI then tells me to configure that trigger. I then enter the serial number of the Button, and don't touch the certificate options, because I already have keys and certificates on my IoT Button. After I made sure that "Enable Trigger" is selected, and click on the "Add" button. Now I'm getting a red box inside the trigger configuration screen saying:

"Empty list of actions is not allowed. At least one action needs to be defined. (Service: AWSIot; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: 41c78c96-00fe-11e8-a48a-61538c57d315)"

I'm stuck at this point, because I never can assign any Trigger to my function.

Comment: Getting the same error here. Tried not checking the box to enable the trigger as well. Someone else posted the same thing on the AWS forums a few days ago, no answer as yet: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=826176

Comment: Might also be worth trying https://iot.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of mucking around but I think I've figured out how to get around this.

The error is strange, because of course you're trying to create an action. It seems like it's a bug.

Fortunately, you can create it around the other way:

- Visit the AWS IoT console
- Go to the Act option in the sidebar menu
- Click Create to create a new rule
- Give a name, and description
- For the SQL rule, build a rule that looks like `SELECT * FROM 'iotbutton/+'` (i.e. enter `*` for Attribute, etc.)
- Add your action - your Lambda function :)
- Add an error action too if you wish
- Click Create Rule

Press your button and confirm that your Lambda function ran!

I'm assuming you could put your button's DSN in place of the `+` in the select statement if you have more than one button.